# how to add single quotes at start and end of value in array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have an array which come from form and i add commas between values with implode. But i have to add single quotes at start and end of values.

```
$form_values = $_GET['values'];
$sql.=" WHERE value IN (".implode(',',$form_values).")";
```

i use this query and it gives a result like that.

```
value1,value2,value3
```

and i use this values for my sql query. But i have to add single quotes also at start and end of these values. It must be like this;

```
'value1','value2','value3'
```

I really don't know how can i add these single quotes.

Comment: `$sql.=" WHERE value IN ('".implode('\',\'',$form_values)."')";`

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements. It will prevent you from SQL injection and solve your problem

Comment: Federkun thanks for your help but i got this error implode(): Invalid arguments passed in. Is there any problem in the query you think?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below.

$sql.=" WHERE value IN ("'"+".implode(',',$form_values).""'")";

Comment: That's not valid php.